# Running rails server on bash a linux system on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am following [this](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10) steps to install ruby on rails in ubuntu or linux subsystem on windows 10.

But this time, I used the updated ruby which is version 2.3.3, rails which is version 5.0.0.1, but after successfull installation of all the requirements, I tried to run this

```
rails new ruby_app
```

in the path `/mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/` which is in windows local c and after a successfull installation I tried running this.

```
rails server
```

I got this problem

```
/home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:40: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/fil/.rbenv/versions in PATH, mode 040777
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
/home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/watcher.rb:74:in `initialize': Invalid argument - Failed to watch "/home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/locale": the given event mask contains no legal events; or fd is not an inotify file descriptor. (Errno::EINVAL)
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:190:in `new'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:190:in `watch'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.7/lib/rb-inotify/notifier.rb:204:in `watch'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/linux.rb:32:in `_configure'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:45:in `block in configure'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `each'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `configure'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/adapter/base.rb:63:in `start'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/backend.rb:28:in `start'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/listener.rb:67:in `block in <class:Listener>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:120:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:120:in `call'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:91:in `transition_with_callbacks!'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/fsm.rb:57:in `transition'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/listen-3.0.8/lib/listen/listener.rb:90:in `start'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:90:in `boot!'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:61:in `initialize'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:59:in `new'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:59:in `initialize_i18n'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:15:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:65:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ruby_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ruby_app/config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
        from /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ruby_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ruby_app/config.ru:in `new'
        from /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ruby_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:318:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:218:in `app'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `app'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:353:in `wrapped_app'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:124:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:77:in `start'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ruby_app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
        from /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ruby_app/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
        from /mnt/c/xampp/htdocs/ruby_app/bin/spring:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Can you give idea what is this? how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't have enough reputation to post as comment but this should provide some answers: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26054

Seems to be a windows related issue from last month.

Haven't used ruby on rails in quite a while so I can't reproduce or test (right now) to see if this is true.

From a comment wich was helpful to others:

> Go to you config/environments/development.rb and comment out the last
>   line, something about watching files and listen gem. can't remember
>   from the top of my head the exact wording, but it is the last line of
>   config
>
> this is new a new method that rails uses to watch changed files, but
>   it doesn't work on WSL
>
> I think guard gem will also fail because of this

Bottom line:
Using rails new --skip-spring --skip-listen gives you a working app

Comment: Thank you, I've been working on the problem for 1 week

Comment: welcome :) installing insider builds of windows should also fix it but yeah you don't know what they're going to break next :)